# How to organize an App composed of Features in Qt?

Tags: architecture, project-structure, modules, qt

When developing a somewhat larger application, with 3-4 screens or so, what is the most common way to organise the code?

I've read that organize-by-feature trumps organize-by-type, so I was considering a structure like so:

```
xyz/Feature1/
  + feature.pro
  + api/f1/header1.h
  + src/f1.cpp
  ...
xyz/Feature2/
  + feature.pro
  + api/f2/header.h
  + src/f2.cpp
  ...
xyz/CommonLibs/...
```

Now I was wondering: these Features are to the app as the wheels to a car.  Is it a good idea to create an `xyz/App/` folder with a project file referring to the Feature folders?  What are the caveats?